# wrong formatting of group by when query execute using sequelize node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, npm, orm, sequelize.js

worked so far

```
model.specialistServiceCategory
    .findAll({ 
      where: { specialistId: req.query.loggedInUserData.userId }
    })
    .then(d => {
      let sServiceCatArr = d.map(i => i.categoryId);
      var searchCond = { 
        where: { status: "OPEN", categoryId: sServiceCatArr, id: { [Op.notIn]: [sequelize.literal("SELECT `bidId` FROM `bid_response` WHERE `specialistId` =" + req.query.loggedInUserData.userId)] } },
      };
      model.bid
        .count(searchCond)
        .then(totalRecord => {
          var totalPage = Math.ceil(totalRecord / limit);
          model.bid
            .findAll({

              where: searchCond.where,
              include: [
                {
                  model: model.requester, attributes: ["id", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "mobile",
                    [sequelize.fn("if", sequelize.literal("profileImage IS NOT NULL"), sequelize.fn("concat", req.app.get("httpUrlUpload"), sequelize.col("profileImage")), ""), "profileImage"]
                  ], required: false
                },  {model:model.bidResponse, attributes:{
    include: ['bidId']
  }, include: {model:model.reviewRating, attributes: [[model.sequelize.fn('AVG', model.sequelize.col('rating')),'avgRating']] } }
                /*{
                  model: model.bidResponse,
                  where: { specialistId: req.query.loggedInUserData.userId },
                  required: false
                }*/
              ],
              limit: limit,
              offset: offset,
              $sort: { id: 1 },
               group: [model.sequelize.literal('`id`')]
            })
            .then(data => util.sendPaginateResponse(res, data, totalRecord, totalPage, page))
            .catch(e => util.handleError(e, res));
        })
        .catch(e => util.handleError(e, res));
    })
    .catch(e => util.handleError(e, res));
```

Query Generated through above Sequelize ORM

```
SELECT `bid`.*, `requester`.`id` AS `requester.id`, `requester`.`firstName` AS `requester.firstName`, `requester`.`lastName` AS `requester.lastName`, `requester`.`email` AS `requester.email`, `requester`.`mobile` AS `requester.mobile`, if(profileImage IS NOT NULL, concat('http://localhost:3002/uploads/', `profileImage`), '') AS `requester.profileImage`, `bidResponses`.`id` AS `bidResponses.id`, `bidResponses`.`bidId` AS `bidResponses.bidId`, `bidResponses`.`specialistId` AS `bidResponses.specialistId`, `bidResponses`.`price` AS `bidResponses.price`, `bidResponses`.`createdAt` AS `bidResponses.createdAt`, `bidResponses`.`updatedAt` AS `bidResponses.updatedAt`, `bidResponses`.`bidId` AS `bidResponses.bidId`, `bidResponses->reviewRatings`.`id` AS `bidResponses.reviewRatings.id`, AVG(`rating`) AS `bidResponses.reviewRatings.avgRating` FROM (SELECT `bid`.`id`, `bid`.`requesterId`, `bid`.`categoryId`, `bid`.`status`, `bid`.`scheduleDate`, `bid`.`expiryDateTime`, `bid`.`description`, `bid`.`latitude`, `bid`.`longitude`, `bid`.`createdAt`, `bid`.`updatedAt` FROM `bid` AS `bid` WHERE `bid`.`status` = 'OPEN' AND `bid`.`categoryId` IN (1, 3, 4) AND `bid`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `bidId` FROM `bid_response` WHERE `specialistId` =6) GROUP BY `id` LIMIT 0, 10) AS `bid` LEFT OUTER JOIN `requester` AS `requester` ON `bid`.`requesterId` = `requester`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `bid_response` AS `bidResponses` ON `bid`.`id` = `bidResponses`.`bidId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `review_rating` AS `bidResponses->reviewRatings` ON `bidResponses`.`specialistId` = `bidResponses->reviewRatings`.`referenceId`;
```

Required Query

```
SELECT `bid`.*, `requester`.`id` AS `requester.id`, `requester`.`firstName` AS `requester.firstName`, `requester`.`lastName` AS `requester.lastName`, `requester`.`email` AS `requester.email`, `requester`.`mobile` AS `requester.mobile`, if(profileImage IS NOT NULL, concat('http://localhost:3002/uploads/', `profileImage`), '') AS `requester.profileImage`, `bidResponses`.`id` AS `bidResponses.id`, `bidResponses`.`bidId` AS `bidResponses.bidId`, `bidResponses`.`specialistId` AS `bidResponses.specialistId`, `bidResponses`.`price` AS `bidResponses.price`, `bidResponses`.`createdAt` AS `bidResponses.createdAt`, `bidResponses`.`updatedAt` AS `bidResponses.updatedAt`, `bidResponses`.`bidId` AS `bidResponses.bidId`, `bidResponses->reviewRatings`.`id` AS `bidResponses.reviewRatings.id`, AVG(`rating`) AS `bidResponses.reviewRatings.avgRating` FROM (SELECT `bid`.`id`, `bid`.`requesterId`, `bid`.`categoryId`, `bid`.`status`, `bid`.`scheduleDate`, `bid`.`expiryDateTime`, `bid`.`description`, `bid`.`latitude`, `bid`.`longitude`, `bid`.`createdAt`, `bid`.`updatedAt` FROM `bid` AS `bid` WHERE `bid`.`status` = 'OPEN' AND `bid`.`categoryId` IN (1, 3, 4) AND `bid`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `bidId` FROM `bid_response` WHERE `specialistId` =6)  LIMIT 0, 10) AS `bid` LEFT OUTER JOIN `requester` AS `requester` ON `bid`.`requesterId` = `requester`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `bid_response` AS `bidResponses` ON `bid`.`id` = `bidResponses`.`bidId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `review_rating` AS `bidResponses->reviewRatings` ON `bidResponses`.`specialistId` = `bidResponses->reviewRatings`.`referenceId` GROUP BY `id`;
```

as you can see the minor difference in the above query in required query the group by is in the last which is representing correct data while in wrong query which is generating through sequelize.js and node is having group by in sub-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I able to solve it using reference of [issue URL](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7778#issuecomment-408164506)
the issue was regarding where clause in sub-query but I faced a similar problem with group by but it fixed my issue too.

I did the following changes in the above code and it worked.

```
  limit: limit,
                  offset: offset,
                  $sort: { id: 1 },
                  subQuery: false,  //this was the change...
                   group: [model.sequelize.literal('`id`'

)]
```